# PHPMyAdmin coletando dados sem necessidade?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Abaixo o código que tenho para coletar os `$_POST`

```
<?php
     $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306",'user1','senhadementirinha');
     $bd = mysql_select_db("recados");
 ?>

    <form name="form" method="post" action="#">
         Nome:
          <input type=text name=nome><br><br>

         E-Mail:
          <input type=text name=email><br><br>

         Mensagem:
           <textarea name=post></textarea><br><br>

         <input type=submit value=Enviar>

         <input type=reset value=Limpar>
    </form>

<?php

    $nome=$_POST['nome'];         
    $post=$_POST['post'];
    $data = date("Y/m/d");

      $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO msg(nome,post,data) values ('$nome','$post','$date')");

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM msg ORDER BY id desc";

      $executar = mysql_query($sql);    

   while( $exibir = mysql_fetch_array($executar)){
        echo $exibir['date'];
        echo $exibir['post'];
        echo "</br><hr>";
   }

?>
```

esse código e usado em loop em uma tabela, porém consegui inserir e colocar o comentário na linha da tabela, mas quando atualiza ele, as outras linhas enviam para o banco de dados espaços vazios.

Uma forma de resolver seria ter um checkbox mas não sei se é possível depois de selecionado, ele permanecer mesmo depois de atualizar a pagina.

Comment: Meu complicado entender a sua duvida, mas acho que é isso: verifica se existe uma session, se não existir faz insert e cria uma session após o insert.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
<?php
$nome=$_POST['nome'];         
$post=$_POST['post'];
$data = date("Y/m/d");

/* Verifica se existe valores a inserir */
if($nome != null &&
      $post != null &&
      $data != null){

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO msg(nome,post,data) 
values('$nome','$post','$date')");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM msg ORDER BY id desc";


$executar = mysql_query($sql);

while( $exibir = mysql_fetch_array($executar)){
echo $exibir['date'];

echo $exibir['post'];
echo "</br><hr>";
}

} /* fim do if != null */

?>
```

Comment: Por favor, explique a solução.

Comment: De acordo com a questão:
"as outras linhas enviam para o banco de dados espaços vazios."
Então o que fiz foi validar se as informações não é null com o código em baixo do comentário:
/* Verifica se existe valores a inserir */